# Appear effect on background image instead of <img> - Cursor trails jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I found [this awesome effect](https://codepen.io/chrisdoble/pen/WQLLVp) on codepen and I want to implement this effect [on my own website on the background](https://gamekeys-shop.de).

But the problem I have to face here is that the background image get set by wordpress and a plugin called visual composer. At the background image gets set as css backgorund image and not as an `<img>` div. But the code you see above on codepen.io is dealing with an `<img>` div.

So, I want to transfer and customize this code for my website to get it working there. The `<div>` in which you can find the background image on my website where I want to appear this effect is called ``. You can get the `<div>` of it by typing this in your console:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("vc_custom_1493329568717")
```

I already tried to recreate this effect on a [local level](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzLxINxZFzovczIwRUVXcl93Q3c). But I only could do it with an `<img>` div. So, here is my question. Does anybody has an idea, how I can transfer this effect to my website?

I would be very happy about an idea or an answer.

Kind regards and Thank You!

Comment: My first thought is that you wont be able to do this with a css background image. You basically need to be able to manipulate the image data with javascript. I could be wrong but one you set the image css. If you are set on this, what you could do is create an image, keep it hidden. when you make the changes to the image, update the css background to be that image.

Comment: And how could I do this?

Comment: Because I found this webpage and here it is working as background image: https://www.canva.com/